How to replicate shinobi (PS2) scarf in 2d
How can I create an effect similar to the to scarf animation in the PS2 game Shinobi as shown below, but in 2D? I use GameMaker but any answer that points me in the right direction is welcome.


A good place to start might be a "trail renderer" — something that remembers a queue of recent positions (places the neck has been) and constructs a strip of geometry joining them. You can find existing documentation about how to implement this type of particle ribbon.

Another thing to check is verlet physics / integration. Looks like there's a couple of options in the GameMaker market place including a free one. See also Sabastian Lague's  related explainer video.
